# How to wrap multiple instances of selected elements into new <div>'s

Tags: jquery, dom, dom-manipulation

I need to wrap the `div`'s with the classes `.left` and `.right` into a new `div`. Having problems making this work as I need it to.

This is the original markup:

```
<div class="content-main">
  <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_3547">
    <div class="share"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_12739">
    <div class="share"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>        
  <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_4">
    <div class="share"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is the result I need:

```
<div class="content-main">
   <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_3547">
      <div class="share"></div>
      <div class="summary-inside">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_12739">
      <div class="share"></div>
      <div class="summary-inside">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="summary" id="listing_summary_4">
      <div class="share"></div>
      <div class="summary-inside">
         <div class="left"></div>
         <div class="right"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The script tag needs to reside within in the  tags (no access to  section). jQuery version is 1.3.2

The closest I am able to get on my own is:

```
    $('.summary .left,.summary .right').wrapAll('<div class="summary-inside"></div>')
```

However the result is wrong, the elements get all put together instead of being distributed the way I need them to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now tested, and does, indeed, work:

```
$('.content-main .summary').each(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.left,.right').wrapAll('<div class="summary-inside"></div>');
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dDrQh/).

The text in the linked demo showing the html that you want is the updated html of the `.content-main` element, after manipulation with jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: Glad to have been of help! =)